# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception Issue

Tags: java

I'm currently receiving an out of bounds issue in my array and I'm really unsure where exactly I've went wrong here. I'm really looking for a second pair of eyes over this thing as I'm going to lose my mind.

I honestly appreciate any help given.
No really: Thanks.

```
package com.jpmorgan.spring.csv;

import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.IOException;

public class CSVRead {  
    static void read() throws IOException { 
        String csvFileToRead = "profit.csv";  
        BufferedReader br = null;  
        String line = "";  
        String splitBy = ",";  

        try {  
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead));  

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                String[] array = line.split(splitBy);  
                System.out.println("Equity & Bonds: [Instrument Type= " + array[0] + " , Name="  + array[1] + " , Quantity=" + array[2] 
                                + " , Buy=" + array[3] + " , Sell=" + array[4] +  /*" , Coupon=" + array[5] +*/ "]");
            }

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        finally {  
            if (br != null) {  
                try {  
                    br.close();  
                } catch (IOException e) {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }
            } 
        }
        System.out.println("Done reading CSV file");
    }
}
```

This is the full CSV file.
I've tried using debug but it's not been much help.

```
instrument_type,name,quantity,buy_price,sell_price,coupon
Equity,AAA,123,1.01,1.10
Equity,BBBB,3,1.05,1.01
Bond,CCC,3,,,0.13
Equity,AAA,12,1.11,1.13
Bond,DD,3,,,1.24
```

Main class for reference.

```
/**
 * Main class is menu driven, receives CSV input.
 * This program reads, calculates and writes CSV files.
 * @author David McNeill
 * @version 1.0 - 17/03/1015
 */

package com.jpmorgan.spring.csv;
import java.util.Scanner;   
public class CSVMain{

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userChoice;
        boolean quit = false;
        do {
        System.out.println("Please choose an option using 1 - 4");                      //print text to screen
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");                     //print text to screen
        System.out.println("1: Read 'input' CSV file");                                 //print text to screen
        System.out.println("2: Calculate 'input' CSV file");                            //print text to screen
        System.out.println("3: Write calculation result to CSV file");                  //print text to screen
        System.out.println("4: Exit program");                                          //print text to screen
            userChoice = in.nextInt();                                                  //'in' equals integer
            if (userChoice == 4)                                                        //when '3' is input then...
                  quit = true;                                                          //the program will now quit
            else if (userChoice == 1)                                                   //when '1' is input then...
                    CSVRead.read();
            else if (userChoice == 2);
                //####################calculations go here#########################             
                //####################calculations go here#########################
                //####################calculations go here#########################
            else if (userChoice == 3)
                    CSVWrite.write();
        } while (!quit);
    }
}
```

Comment: can u update question with first few rows of the CSV??

Comment: Your code assumes that `line.split(splitBy)` will return an array with at least 5 entries (6 with the commented-out bit). Apparently it isn't. So you have to look at the line and figure out why. A debugger is the best way to do that, single-stepping through the code.

Comment: Yes, debug it from `split` method. Plus if the file has some different headers, it will cause issues. that's why I am asking first 2-3 rows.

Comment: once you call the proper function it works fine. see my answer below with the full code and the output

Answer (score 0):

After splitting the line you should make sure you're getting the right number of columns.

I can't tell you how to fix the potentially bad data but I can help you identify it. Just replace the inner loop with this:

```
int lineNum = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
    String[] array = line.split(splitBy);
    if (array.length < 5)
        throw new Exception("There's a problem with " + csvFileToRead + " on line " + lineNum + ":\n" + line);          
    System.out.println("Equity & Bonds: [Instrument Type= " + array[0] + " , Name="  + array[1] + " , Quantity=" + array[2] 
                            + " , Buy=" + array[3] + " , Sell=" + array[4] +  /*" , Coupon=" + array[5] +*/ "]");
    lineNum++;
}
```

Comment: And how do I do that exactly?

Comment: @David I added an example to help you debug the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Your exception now appears to show there's a problem on line 0 of the csv.

Comment: @David what did it print as the first line? that should have been the second line of the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

your CSVRead has no main method.. change the call to  `CSVRead.read();`

```
import java.util.Scanner;   
public class CSVMain{

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userChoice;
        boolean quit = false;
        do {
        System.out.println("Please choose an option using 1 - 4");                      //print text to screen
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");                     //print text to screen
        System.out.println("1: Read 'input' CSV file");                                 //print text to screen
        System.out.println("2: Calculate 'input' CSV file");                            //print text to screen
        System.out.println("3: Write calculation result to CSV file");                  //print text to screen
        System.out.println("4: Exit program");                                          //print text to screen
            userChoice = in.nextInt();                                                  //'in' equals integer
            if (userChoice == 4)                                                        //when '3' is input then...
                  quit = true;                                                          //the program will now quit
            else if (userChoice == 1)                                                   //when '1' is input then...
                    CSVRead.read();
            else if (userChoice == 2);
                //####################calculations go here#########################             
                //####################calculations go here#########################
                //####################calculations go here#########################
        } while (!quit);
    }
}
```

CSVRead.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.IOException;

public class CSVRead {  
    static void read() throws IOException { 
        String csvFileToRead = "profit.csv";  
        BufferedReader br = null;  
        String line = "";  
        String splitBy = ",";  

        try {  
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead));  

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                String[] array = line.split(splitBy);  
                System.out.println("Equity & Bonds: [Instrument Type= " + array[0] + " , Name="  + array[1] + " , Quantity=" + array[2] 
                                + " , Buy=" + array[3] + " , Sell=" + array[4] +  /*" , Coupon=" + array[5] +*/ "]");
            }

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        finally {  
            if (br != null) {  
                try {  
                    br.close();  
                } catch (IOException e) {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }
            } 
        }
        System.out.println("Done reading CSV file");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Please choose an option using 1 - 4
------------------------------------
1: Read 'input' CSV file
2: Calculate 'input' CSV file
3: Write calculation result to CSV file
4: Exit program
1
Equity & Bonds: [Instrument Type= instrument_type , Name=name , Quantity=quantity , Buy=buy_price , Sell=sell_price]
Equity & Bonds: [Instrument Type= Equity , Name=AAA , Quantity=123 , Buy=1.01 , Sell=1.10]
Equity & Bonds: [Instrument Type= Equity , Name=BBBB , Quantity=3 , Buy=1.05 , Sell=1.01]
Equity & Bonds: [Instrument Type= Bond , Name=CCC , Quantity=3 , Buy= , Sell=]
Equity & Bonds: [Instrument Type= Equity , Name=AAA , Quantity=12 , Buy=1.11 , Sell=1.13]
Equity & Bonds: [Instrument Type= Bond , Name=DD , Quantity=3 , Buy= , Sell=]
Done reading CSV file
```

ALTERNATIVELY, rename `read` method to `main` in `CSVRead`

```
class public class CSVRead {  
    static void main() throws IOException {
```

then call it like you do  `CSVRead.main();` in `CSVMain` class

Comment: Just tried running this with my actual main class and I'm still getting the same exception that I am out of bounds. This is very frustrating. My main class is calling in the method for this via if else menu set up.

Comment: what is your main class ? You are obviously doing something else wrong cuz I just ran it and it works as I told you

Comment: Edited the first post with the whole main

Comment: there is no main method in CSVRead are you sure you posted the right code ?

Comment: i edited my answer. once you call the proper function it works fine.

Comment: Scroll down, the main class is there in the original post. There was no 'main' method in CSVRead because it didn't seem necessary?

Comment: Lol man, do you even know your code? did you even write it ? can't you see the following line in "your" code :  `else if (userChoice == 1)                                                   //when '1' is input then...
                    CSVRead.main(arg); ` . just see my answer, write the code the way I do it and everything will work fine, don't make a bigger deal out of it than it really is

Comment: I was trying another users 'fix' I must have copy and pasted the wrong thing but even when I've copied and pasted everything you've got here I'm still receiving the exception.

Comment: Once you are convinced my code works, please accept my answer as described here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . Thanks

Comment: use Sublime Text 2 as an editor, create a new file called profit.csv, copy paste the data you want as input, run the .java program using command line, and I assure you everything will work fine. you are getting screwed by how you read your .csv file obviously..